# Converting shapefile to postgis without giving bounding box

Tags: postgis, shapefile, ogr2ogr

```
ogr2ogr -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES -f PostgreSQL PG:"<myconnection>" 
-lco DIM=2 /path/to/myshapefilename.shp myshapefilename -overwrite -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -lco FID=id 
-spat 3513207.8,5731702.6 3513579.6,5731962.9 -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI
```

-spat is defined as

```
spat xmin ymin xmax ymax:

spatial query extents. Only features whose geometry intersects the extents will be selected. The geometries will not be clipped unless -clipsrc is specified
```

I want to convert the whole shapefile without limits of a bounding box. Can I do that?

Comment: Why not just not supply the bounding box in the first place (leave out the -spat parameters)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YES**

The `-spat` switch is completely optional, and the typical use case is probably *not* to use it. I never use it, because when doing a shapefile import I have never needed only part of the shapefile (or I would rather get it all into PostGIS and then do a spatial selection there). `ogr2ogr` will run and import all features in the shapefile.

Your statement reproduced without the undesired option:

```
ogr2ogr -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES -f PostgreSQL PG:"<myconnection>" 
-lco DIM=2 /path/to/myshapefilename.shp myshapefilename -overwrite 
-lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -lco FID=id -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI
```

Do be clear on what each option means, and that you are doing what you intend.

- `-lco DIM=2` is only necessary if your shapefile has a Z dimension or a measure (M coordinate). In my experience this is uncommon, but this probably depends on your area of research.
- `-overwrite` will trash an existing layer. Often the desired behavior, but if you would rather append new records, leave it off.
- `-lco FID=id` will be your primary key field. The name is of course arbitrary, though it seems that PostGIS developers have settled on `gid` as a common choice.
- `-nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI` is almost always necessary, as the shapefile format is sloppy about mixing simple and multi geometries, while PostGIS is strict about treating them as different data types.

Comment: small correction. Shapefiles supports 2d,3d (z or m ) and 4d ( z and m) geoms.

Comment: Thanks for info about 3d and 4d shapefiles. I've updated answer. Is the edit reasonable or should I just delete that first bullet point?

Answer (score 2):

ogr2ogr/ogrinfo are great tools...but also...PostgreSQL provides two built-in tools for exporting (pgsql2shp) and loading (shp2pgsql) shapefiles. They are easy to use and well documented...see the [docs](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html) and this [cheat sheet](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg). Quoting the PostGIS 2.0 docs:

> An example session using the loader to create an input file and
> uploading it might look like this:
>
> --shp2pgsql -c -D -s 4269 -i -I shaperoads.shp myschema.roadstable > roads.sql
>
> --psql -d roadsdb -f roads.sql
>
> A conversion and upload can be done all in one step using UNIX pipes:
>
> --shp2pgsql shaperoads.shp myschema.roadstable | psql -d roadsdb

The switches in the first example instruct the loader to: (-c) [default] create & populate a new table; (-D) use DUMP instead of SQL inserts; (-s) pass or transform/pass SRID to geometry columns; (-i) specify data type for INT fields; and (-I) automagically index geometry fields. Nothing too terribly daunting...

So in your case it may be as simple as:

```
shp2pgsql /path/to/myshpfile.shp schema.newtablename | psql -d yourdb
```

Just another approach to consider...